# How do I use music-streaming plugins on custom Trackmania 2 servers?

Tags: trackmania-2

Some Trackmania 2: Stadium servers have plugins that stream out music to players. I can't get them to play, even though sound effects are enabled in-game. How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Peer to peer settings and "locator" settings may cause issues with music plugins.

1. Start the Trackmania 2 Launcher

[image]

2. Configure your settings

[image]

3. Go advanced

[image]

4. Enable certain peer-to-peer settings

Clear your cache, and make sure your cache is big enough. I set it at 8000 MB just in case. "Locators" seem to be ways to download Trackmania 2 content from websites rather than the game servers themselves.

There's a chance that the peer-to-peer settings weren't causing the music issues, but I enabled them just in case.

[image]

5. Go advanced in peer-to-peer

Again, peer-to-peer may be unrelated, but the "locators" are probably good to enable.

[image]

6. Save and accept your settings. Make sure you use this profile to launch the game.